# d3.js join rotating group with line

Tags: d3.js

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jogavo/1/edit?html,js,output) of what I have so far.  I have a rotating group on the right hand side that simulates a circle turning with a smaller circle on the circumference.  There is a vertical line in a different group to the left of the group.

What I want to achieve is to have a horizontal line joining the smaller circle to the vertical line as the group rotates.

How is this possible?

Comment: How do you want your horizontal line to join your vertical line? In the middle? Top corner? Bottom corner? Or maybe it should slide along the height of the vertical line?

Comment: @iulian yes, it should slide along the height of the vertical line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you just need to update the x2,y2 positions of the line like so :

```
 d3.select('.outsideline').attr('x1', 0)
            .attr('y1', 20).attr('x2', circleOutsideCo.left-140)
            .attr('y2', circleOutsideCo.top-215)
```

These are updated with the coordinates of the circle worked out by `getClientBoundingBox()`:

```
 var circleOutside = document.getElementsByClassName('circle-guide')[0];
     circleOutsideCo = circleOutside.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Notice I have hardcoded numbers there too. These are to make up for the margins etc.

There was a couple things added, class names for the line etc but here is an updated fiddle (I rather use that than JSBin :P personal preference) : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/L5dc8guf/

Just re read your question. You wanted that outside line to stay there and create another joing that one and the outside circle. I just added another line :

```
 sineWaveGroup.append('line')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', 20)
    .attr('x2', 0)
    .attr('y2', 200)
    .style('stroke', 'steelblue').attr('class', 'joiningLine');
```

And used this different class in the selection :

```
 d3.select('.joiningLine').attr('x1', 0) ....
```

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/L5dc8guf/2/

Edit 3

I read your comments. You want it to just go up and down. Then just update the y1 position. Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/L5dc8guf/3/

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding. But I think the extra work will help you understand how it all works :)